# IGBT excessive Vge

Tags: mosfet, igbt, shoot-through

I have a circuit with a PWM signal controlling the gate of an IGBT. It's a dual IGBT module, SKM150GB12. A relay delivers voltage to the collector, 2, and the power is delivered to a battery, Vbat+ on 1 and Vbat- on 3. 1 IGBT is for charging, the other is for discharging.

If I accidently leave the gate disconnected, the circuit destroys itself. I'm aware of false triggering and a possible shoot through if both IGBTs turn on at the same time. But I'm seeing something different. With the gate of the top IGBT floating, 8, if I apply collector voltage, the Vge will rise to >40V and destroy the IGBT. It's not breaking from shoot through current, it's breaking from excessive Vge. How is this happening if the gate is not connected?
[image]

Comment: My guess, and it's only a guess (so not an answer) is that there's an ESD protection structure on the gate that has some small leakage that can charge the gate capacitance from the collector.  Of course you should never leave an IGBT or FET gate floating, it's asking for trouble.

Comment: That's possible, I'll check the datasheet for more info about that. It was left floating unintentionally and I'm just trying to work out exactly what happened.